# OWIN Authentication Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application I am working on right now that I am integrating OWIN authentication into. I currently have my app configured in the startup class as so

```
// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, // "ApplicationCookie",
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Producer/LogIn/")
});
```

This is working great. But I have a few areas in my code where I need to know the login path. I am not looking to directly call a method to log out the user and redirect them, I just need the value of the PathString.

I could hard code it of course as its a value that wouldn't change often, (if ever) but I hate to do that and I want a solution that I can reuse in other projects cleanly. I would prefer to be able to access this value programmatically.

TIA.

Comment: I'm hard pressed to think of any valid reason your app needs to know this.  The whole point of OWIN is to move this sort of thing to a different layer and decouple it from your app.  Now you want to re-couple it for some unspecified reason.  Simply logging the user out will redirect them to the login page, so your app doesn't need to know the url to redirect them.  It's a separate module for a reason, and should remain that way.

Comment: Well, in this particular case, I need to string to create a link to display to the user. As I mentioned, I do not want to log the user out necessarily.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `@Url.Action("LogIn", "Producer")`?  Why do you need to get this string from OWIN?  Identity is just redirecting to a Controller/Action, so why not use the link generated by routing for that Controller/Action?

Comment: While that certainly isn't hard coding it, and its making good use of the Razor syntax, its just not the solution I am hoping to find. I am looking for a solution that is more flexible than that. I may need to have knowledge of that particular string for another reason down the line, who's to say? Even if I just use the Razor syntax, I would still want to know if that data can be accessed and how.